# Cmake compiler "not found" warnings, cause for concern? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, compilation, cmake, compiler-warnings

Can I safely ignore these cmake compiler warnings?

I'm learning to compile packages from source and practicing on MySQL.

Should I be searching for and installing dev libraries when I see "notices" like this (referencing specific "not found" files):

```
$ cmake . -LA
...
-- Looking for include file cxxabi.h
-- Looking for include file cxxabi.h - not found.
-- Looking for include file dirent.h
-- Looking for include file dirent.h - found
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - found
```

And what should I do about notices referencing these "not found" messages:

```
-- Looking for bmove
-- Looking for bmove - not found
-- Looking for bsearch
-- Looking for bsearch - found
-- Looking for index
-- Looking for index - found
```

For example, cxxabi.h can be found in libstdc++6-4.7-dev on Debian. Do I need to install libstdc++6-4.7-dev to have a proper compile of MySQL?

I also have some (constant?) warnings that I'm unsure of:

```
-- Performing Test TIME_T_UNSIGNED
-- Performing Test TIME_T_UNSIGNED - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_GETADDRINFO
-- Performing Test HAVE_GETADDRINFO - Success
```

Overall, my build seems to work good, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CMake configuration process doesn't fail, it means these headers are optional and there are workarounds in the MySQL code for these cases.

It might be also, that when some headers aren't present some features are silently turned off. It make sense to provide MySQL as many optional headers as you can.

Beware that some headers are OS-specific, so you can't and don't have to provide them.

Comment: Appreciate the info. I can find the missing files easy enough, but do you have any suggestions on how I can find the missing *non-file* notices? For example, missing above is `bmove`. Is that a function? Do you know how to track those down?

Comment: You can use `man` command on Unix-like OSes and Google. `bmove` is a deprecated system call.